# Date Field shows the word 'true' instead of a calendar after clicking the date picker

Tags: 2010, calendar, datepicker

We're having this problem across all of our sites since migrating to SP2010. Occasionally (let's say 1/50 times), when you click the Calendar icon on a date, instead of seeing a calendar, you see the word "true" written where a calendar should be. The area that would normally occupy a calendar is white, suggesting that a div tag has been added to the page, but there is no calendar. You cannot dismiss the fake-calendar. You have to refresh the page. Below is an image of the problem. We can't determine any sort of pattern or correlation. I haven't been able to find anyone else having this problem online when I searched.

Has anyone else experienced this? Have you come up with a solution or figured out a cause?

[image: The calendar shows the word 'true' instead of an actual calendar]

Comment: I'm having the same issue in my solution, which still doesn't exist in a production environment. So, either if I spend quite a while without accessing my deployed app, or if I make a new deployment, then, the first time I'll click a SharePoint:DateTimeControl it has like a 1/4 chance of taking quite a while to load, in which case it will usually display this "true" box instead of the calendar. My master is about the same as v4.master, with just a few extra divs and an ul/li menu. Any suggestions are welcome

Comment: I ended up using a script link to add jquery to all the pages on my sites to just use jquery date pickers instead of the junky sharepoint ones. If I remember, I'll provide an example on Monday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems this is a timing issue and may be exacerbated by network slow down. This control issues an ajax call back to the server and if the response takes more than a second to come back, that gives the user a chance to click a 2nd time on the icon (issuing a 2nd ajax call).  Whent the calendar pops up (with the div), the javascript gets confused and only closes the calendar and NOT the div as well. It's probably a parent/child issue since the div is probably opened with the 1st request and the calendar was created by the 2nd click request.

You can reproduce the issue very easily if you can catch your network when it's relatively slow. You just have to click the icon a 2nd time before the calenar pops up. THen when the calendar pops up and you select a date, you will see the problem.  I found that sometimes you have to triple click, but I could easily replicate it.

As a work around, you should be able to add javascript to the page that disables the calendar icon/button in the 'onclick' event (to prevent people from clicking that 2nd time), then when the response comes back, re-enable the icon/button.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! We never were sure what had caused this. It seemed to happen usually on our (slow) test server, and even then, usually after an IIS reset. Now we know why!

Answer (score 1):

I still haven't found why this happens sometimes, but I've found that the best solution is to just replace SharePoint's obsolete datepicker with the one from jQuery-ui. You can do this with a Script Link feature:

```
function ImproveDateTextBoxs() {
    $("input[id$='DateTimeField_DateTimeFieldDate']").each(function () {
        ImproveDate($(this));
    });
}

function ImproveDate(obj) {

    obj.focus(function () { obj.select(); });

    if (typeof jQuery.ui.datepicker != "undefined") {
        obj.datepicker({
            showOtherMonths: true,
                selectOtherMonths: true,
            showButtonPanel: true,
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
        });

    obj.parent().next().children("a").removeAttr('onclick');
    obj.parent().next().children("a").click(function () { obj.select(); });
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting "You must specify a valid date within the range of 1/01/1900 and 31/12/8900." error when I save.

Answer (score 1):

This might be too late to help you guys but if your master page sets the compatibility to IE8
 then this should solve your problem. It seems to mess up with anything above.

EDIT: It actually seems to only mess up with IE 11

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a custom master page then I would try switching the site back to v4.master and then retesting just this functionality.  If it is suddenly resolved then it means that something in your custom javascript is interfering with the SharePoint scripts.

Custom solutions that inject custom controls into delegates is another place to check but those are pretty rare.

Answer (score 0):

I am also having the same issue which you asked in this page.
Finally I got two solution for this issue.

First:

1. You have to change the `datepicker.js` from your layout folder.
   Because the `datepicker.js` has been broken due to some upgrading in browser.
   the path: `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS`.
2. You have to change the `datepickerv4.css` from your style folder.
   due to some style changes also it affect the datepicker control function.
   the path: `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\1033\STYLES`.
3. Please verify whether your `datepicker.js` and `datepicker.debug.js` file is in the layout folder.
4. Please verify the datepicker.css is in both the path as i mention here below:

   ```
   path1:C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\1033\STYLES

   path2:C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\1033\STYLES\Themable
   ```

Finally, close all your browser and restart the browser you will get the clear date picker control.

Answer (score 0):

Second:

1.In the site, once the date picker is appearing as a white box:
press the F12 key on your keyboard, and select the date picker icon and see the css in the developer tool box. The `.ms-quicklaunch` class has the visibility of hidden or visible.

```
.ms-quicklaunch  
{  
visibility:hidden !important;  
}
```

you have to change the visibility  from hidden to visible as shown below:

```
.ms-quicklaunch
{
visibility:visible !important;
}
```

first image is hidden functionality image:[image]

Second is the visible image:
[image]

Or open your site using SharePoint Designer.
Go to all files-- _catalogs--theme--themed--corev4-some number.css--edit the css file and there. See the `.ms-quicklaunch` class as I show in my image below. Change the visibility from hidden to visible.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out a solution. Please take a look at my project:

https://github.com/Jonas-buriti/sharepoint-2010-js

This js fixes other SharePoint 2010 IE >= 11 issues.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the SharePoint SE. Take a look at the [tour](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour) on how to ask and answer questions. Make sure that when answering an question, you include the context to the solution in the answer. Links can break in the future. Check out [How do I write a good answer?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).